# Discord.js slash commands .getMember() and .getChannel() are returning null even though the options are required

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, null, discord-interactions

**EDIT/SOLUTION**: The Guild Members intent needs to be enabled on the developer portal and your bot's client must log in with
`const client = new Client({ intents: [..., GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers] });`

I have a Discord.js bot with this command definition:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('removerole')
        .setDescription("Remove a role from a user. Officer use only.")
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option.setName('target')
                .setDescription("The user whose role should be removed.")
                .setRequired(true))
        .addChannelOption(option =>
            option.setName('gamechannel')
                .setDescription("The channel that is associated with the role to be removed.")
                .setRequired(true)),


    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });

        //collect member
        const member = interaction.options.getMember('target');
        console.log(`member is ${member}`);
        console.log(`user is ${interaction.options.getUser('target')}`);
        
        //rest of function...
    }
}
```

When I input this...

[image]

...this is printed:

```
member is null
user is null
```

And the rest of this function that relies on these variables throws an error because it's trying to read a value of a null.
The slash command options are required, so they should have a value, but getUser() and getMember() are still returning null. I know I am missing something but I've changed it to be [as close to the guide as possible](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/parsing-options.html#command-options) which should work.

Why are the values null?

Comment: Not sure, but do you have the respective intents?

Comment: What discord.js version are you on?

Comment: @DarshanB v14.7.1

Comment: @ArnavMishra I don't have any intents enabled but I don't think the Server Member intent is required for this.

Comment: @ArnavMishra After enabling it and coming back the next day this seems to have worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you enable the required intents, namely the `GuildMembers` and whichever other data you are using.

[Which intents are available](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayIntentBits)

[What are intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#gateway-intents)